# What is this error on this code (CNN and SVM classification)

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, classification, svm

what is the problem?

here the link on github:

https://gist.github.com/moemous/5eeae0711002604d3c6f04a667cccea8

```
     ValueError                                Traceback (most recent 
     call last)
     <ipython-input-37-fd99ba55a36e> in <module>()
     7 for i in range(epochs):
     8   print('Starting run: {}'.format(i))
     ----> 9   wrapper.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=1, batch_size=64)
     10   accuracy["with_svm"].append(wrapper.evaluate(x_test, y_test))
     11   accuracy["without_svm"].append(

     3 frames
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/engine/training_utils.py 
    in standardize_input_data(data, names, shapes, check_batch_axis, 
    exception_prefix)
    136                             ': expected ' + names[i] + ' to have 
    shape ' +
     137                             str(shape) + ' but got array with 
     shape ' +
      --> 138                             str(data_shape))
     139     return data
      140 

       ValueError: Error when checking input: expected conv2d_7_input to 
      have shape (256, 256, 1) but got array with shape (256, 256, 3)
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is clear, the shape of your input data is not the same as the input shape in your model definition (first Conv2D layer), but whats wrong with that?

You use RGB image and it has 3 different channel for each color, so your input shape in model should be `input_shape=(256, 256, 3)` instead of `input_shape=(256, 256, 1)`.

Black and White images have only one channel, so for Black and White images you should use `input_shape=(256, 256, 1)`.

Comment: I tired this before but its still doesn't work.

https://gist.github.com/moemous/b0abc82260be35efe44663c368caddf6

Answer (score 0):

reshapes it to (1, 150, 150, 3) !

You should reshape in this way for keras. (-1, 150, 150, 1) and input shape (150,150,1).

Comment: it's still doesn't work my friend:

https://gist.github.com/moemous/81cc3c44b9e9253081faa67c9df8afcf

Comment: Try it. https://gist.github.com/gkhan496/7e36e23cc89ea73326541f8074671c50

Comment: still doesnt work
look at this bro:
https://gist.github.com/moemous/ac6c0bb553f56e617f3448d3e4ddbacf

Comment: Bro you should change this code _image_size = tuple((256, 256))

width=256
height=256
depth=3 to default_image_size = tuple((150, 150))
width=150
height=150
depth=1

Comment: still the same @gkhan496 :
check this out:
https://gist.github.com/moemous/52128618dcc44501bb2e0ea266dc758b